# Transform columns from Character to POSIXt

Tags: r, date

I have this data.frame:

```
df
  Date          A_F.t.   Date.1        A_S.t.    Date.2    B_F.t.     Date.3    B_S.t.     Date.4    C_F.t.     Date.5    C_S.t.
1 1988-12-29   1.7852 27-Dec-88      1.804000 1988-12-29 0.8360505 28-Dec-88  0.836820 1988-12-29 0.007959249 28-Dec-88  0.007963
2 1988-12-30   1.8027 28-Dec-88      1.789000 1988-12-30 0.8368901 29-Dec-88  0.838574 1988-12-30 0.008019246 29-Dec-88  0.007946
3 1989-01-04   1.8001 29-Dec-88      1.789500 1989-01-03 0.8394889 30-Dec-88  0.838364 1989-01-03 0.008113590 30-Dec-88  0.007997
4 1989-01-10   1.7572 30-Dec-88      1.808500 1989-01-04 0.8371704  2-Jan-89        ND 1989-01-04 0.008019246  2-Jan-89        ND
5 1989-01-16   1.7540  2-Jan-89           ND  1989-01-05 0.8368201  3-Jan-89  0.839842 1989-01-06 0.007930843  3-Jan-89  0.008091
6 1989-01-17   1.7655  3-Jan-89      1.822500 1989-01-06 0.8380825  4-Jan-89  0.838856 1989-01-09 0.007947230  4-Jan-89  0.007997
```

the  class of Forward$Date,Forward$Date.2,Forward$Date.4 is `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

the  class of Forward$Date.1,Forward$Date.3,Forward$Date.5 is character

how can I turn to `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` only the columns `Forward$Date.1`,`Forward$Date.3` and `Forward$Date.5`?

When i use `as.POSIXct(as.Date(x,"%d-%b-%y"))` as Ben suggested my df went like this:

```
df
      Date          A_F.t.   Date.1        A_S.t.    Date.2    B_F.t.     Date.3    B_S.t.     Date.4    C_F.t.     Date.5    C_S.t.
1 1988-12-29   1.7852                <NA>     1.804000 1988-12-29 0.8360505                <NA> 0.836820 1988-12-29 0.007959249                <NA> 0.007963
2 1988-12-30   1.8027                <NA>     1.789000 1988-12-30 0.8368901                <NA> 0.838574 1988-12-30 0.008019246                <NA> 0.007946
3 1989-01-04   1.8001                <NA>     1.789500 1989-01-03 0.8394889                <NA> 0.838364 1989-01-03 0.008113590                <NA> 0.007997
4 1989-01-10   1.7572                <NA>     1.808500 1989-01-04 0.8371704 1989-01-01 22:00:00       ND 1989-01-04 0.008019246 1989-01-01 22:00:00       ND
5 1989-01-16   1.7540 1989-01-01 22:00:00          ND  1989-01-05 0.8368201 1989-01-02 22:00:00 0.839842 1989-01-06 0.007930843 1989-01-02 22:00:00 0.008091
6 1989-01-17   1.7655 1989-01-02 22:00:00     1.822500 1989-01-06 0.8380825 1989-01-03 22:00:00 0.838856 1989-01-09 0.007947230 1989-01-03 22:00:00 0.007997
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
Date          A_F.t.   Date.1        A_S.t.    Date.2    B_F.t.     Date.3    B_S.t.     Date.4    C_F.t.     Date.5    C_S.t.
1 1988-12-29   1.7852 27-Dec-88      1.804000 1988-12-29 0.8360505 28-Dec-88  0.836820 1988-12-29 0.007959249 28-Dec-88  0.007963
2 1988-12-30   1.8027 28-Dec-88      1.789000 1988-12-30 0.8368901 29-Dec-88  0.838574 1988-12-30 0.008019246 29-Dec-88  0.007946
3 1989-01-04   1.8001 29-Dec-88      1.789500 1989-01-03 0.8394889 30-Dec-88  0.838364 1989-01-03 0.008113590 30-Dec-88  0.007997
4 1989-01-10   1.7572 30-Dec-88      1.808500 1989-01-04 0.8371704  2-Jan-89        ND 1989-01-04 0.008019246  2-Jan-89        ND
5 1989-01-16   1.7540  2-Jan-89           ND  1989-01-05 0.8368201  3-Jan-89  0.839842 1989-01-06 0.007930843  3-Jan-89  0.008091
6 1989-01-17   1.7655  3-Jan-89      1.822500 1989-01-06 0.8380825  4-Jan-89  0.838856 1989-01-09 0.007947230  4-Jan-89  0.007997")
```

How about:

```
cols.to.fix <- c("Date.1","Date.3","Date.5")
dd[cols.to.fix] <- lapply(dd[cols.to.fix],
       function(x) as.POSIXct(as.Date(x,"%d-%b-%y")))
```

Note that in order to use the `%b` format specifier successfully with this data set, you must have your locale set to one where the month abbreviations match those in your data set; from `strptime` (emphasis added):

> ‘%b’ Abbreviated month name **in the current locale on this
>             platform**.  (Also matches full name on input: in some locales
>             there are no abbreviations of names.)

So something like:

```
old_time <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","C")
## do stuff
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",old_time) ## restore locale
```

should work ...

Comment: Thanks, Ben Bolker!! . But it wasnt as i expected. I edited the question. Could you see for me, please?